# How to add an action bar in kivy using screenmanager widget?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to add an action bar on top in the first screen of my project. I tried using `screenmanager` widget and sending the action bar as it's children like how to manage/get both of the screens. At first I tried just adding the action bar code in root.widget in the first screen, but they are showing the class for this as an invalid class.

How to add both of them? Also I can't show the buttons from top to bottom even though I added `orientation : 'vertical'`

```
    import kivy
    kivy.require('1.10.1')

    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen,FadeTransition

    class SomeLayout_GridLayout(Screen):
        pass
    class FirstScreen(Screen):
        pass
    class SecondScreen(Screen):
        pass
    class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
        pass

    root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
      ScreenManager:
        FirstScreen:
        SecondScreen:
        SomeLayout_GridLayout:
     <FirstScreen>:
        name: 'first'
        <SomeLayout_GridLayout>:
        cols: 1
        rows: 2
        row_force_default: True
        rows_minimum: {0: ActionBar.height, 1: self.height - ActionBar.height}
        SomeMenu_ActionBar:
            id: ActionBar

        <SomeMenu_ActionBar@ActionBar>:
        ActionView:
            id: ActionView
            ActionGroup:
                id: App_ActionGroup
                mode: 'spinner'
                text: 'App'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Settings'
                    on_press: app.open_settings()
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Quit'
                    on_press: app.get_running_app().stop()

            ActionGroup:
                id: File_ActionGroup
                mode: 'spinner'
                text: 'File'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Open'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Save'
    <HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>:
        title: app.title if app.title is not None else 'Action Previous'
        with_previous: False
        app_icon: ''
        app_icon_width: 0
        app_icon_height: 0
        size_hint_x: None
        width: len(self.title) * 10

    <HiddenText_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>: #
        with_previous: False
        on_press: print(self)
        title: ''

    <Hidden_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>:
        with_previous: False
        on_press: print(self)
        title: ''
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 0, 0
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    text: 'Crime Prediction'
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'second'
                Button:
                    text: 'Forum'
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release:  app.root.current = 'second'
                Button:
                    text: 'Probable Suspect'
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'second'
    <SecondScreen>:
        name: 'second'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Predict Crime Nigga!'
                font_size: 50
            BoxLayout:`enter code here`
                Button:
                    text: 'Back to Main Menu'
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'first'
                Button:
                    text: 'get random colour screen'
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'first'
    ''')
    class ScreenManagerApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return root_widget

   ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: Your `<SomeMenu_ActionBar@ActionBar>:` rule is inside the `<FirstScreen>:` rule. Similarly `<SomeLayout_GridLayout>:` is also inside the same rule. That is not allowed. It may be just your indentation is incorrect. Please edit your post to correct your indentation, if that is not your intention. Your post should allow someone to cut and paste your code and run it. Try that with your post.

Comment: One thing I notice is that your `ActionView` does not contain an `ActionPrevious`. The [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.actionbar.html#module-kivy.uix.actionbar) says `An ActionView will contain an ActionPrevious`. Not very clear, but I think that means that you must include an `ActionPrevious` in your `ActionView`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Kivy App with ActionBar & ScreenManager

1. Declare a root widget with inheritance of `BoxLayout`
2. Add `ActionBar` as child of root widget
3. Add `ScreenManager` as child of root widget, and with `id: sm`

### Snippets

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    ActionBar:
        ...

    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        FirstScreen:
        SecondScreen:
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class CrimePrevention(BoxLayout):
    pass


Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class TestApp(App):
    title = 'Kivy ScreenManager & ActionBar Demo'

    def build(self):
        return CrimePrevention()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import sp kivy.metrics.sp
#:import dp kivy.metrics.dp

<CrimePrevention>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            # source: 'data/background.png'

    SomeMenu_ActionBar:
        id: ActionBar

    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        WelcomeScreen:
        FirstScreen:
        SecondScreen:

<SomeMenu_ActionBar@ActionBar>:

    ActionView:
        id: ActionView

        HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious:

        ActionGroup:
            id: App_ActionGroup
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'Jump to Screen'

            ActionButton:
                text: 'Crime Prediction'
                on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current = 'second'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Forum'
                on_release:  app.root.ids.sm.current = 'second'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Probable Suspect'
                on_release:  app.root.ids.sm.current = 'second'

        ActionGroup:
            id: App_ActionGroup
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'App'

            ActionButton:
                text: 'Settings'
                on_press: app.open_settings()
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Quit'
                on_press: app.get_running_app().stop()

        ActionGroup:
            id: File_ActionGroup
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'File'

            ActionButton:
                text: 'Open'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Save'

<HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>:
    title: ''   # app.title if app.title is not None else 'Action Previous'
    with_previous: False
    app_icon: ''
    app_icon_width: 0
    app_icon_height: 0
    size_hint_x: None
    width: len(self.title) * 10

<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'welcome'
    Label:
        text: 'Welcome Screen'
        font_size: sp(50)

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    Label:
        text: 'First Screen'

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Predict Crime'
            font_size: 50

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Back to Main Menu'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current = 'first'
            Button:
                text: 'get random colour screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current = 'first'
```

## Output

[image: Kivy ActionBar & ScreenManager]